# How do I make my sphinx directive add assets to _static folder?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, directive, read-the-docs, docutils

I'm building a custom sphinx extension and Directive to render interactive charts on sphinx and ReadTheDocs. The actual data for a chart resides in a `.json` file.

In a `.rst` document, including a chart looks like this:

```
.. chart:: charts/test.json
    :width: 400px
    :height: 250px

    This is the caption of the chart, yay...
```

---

The steps I take are:

1. Render the documentation with a placeholder the same size as the chart (a loading spinner)
2. Use jQuery (in an added javascript file) to get the URI (which I add as an attribute to the dom node in my Directive) of the json file (in this case `charts/test.json`)
3. Use jQuery to fetch the file and parse the JSON
4. On successful fetch of the data, use the plotly library to render it into a chart and use jQuery to remove the placeholder

---

The directive looks like:

```
class PlotlyChartDirective(Directive):
    """ Top-level plotly chart directive """

    has_content = True

    def px_value(argument):
        # This is not callable as self.align.  We cannot make it a
        # staticmethod because we're saving an unbound method in
        # option_spec below.
        return directives.length_or_percentage_or_unitless(argument, 'px')

    required_arguments = 1
    optional_arguments = 0

    option_spec = {
        # TODO allow static images for PDF renders   'altimage': directives.unchanged,
        'height': px_value,
        'width': px_value,
    }

    def run(self):
        """ Parse a plotly chart directive """

        self.assert_has_content()
        env = self.state.document.settings.env
        # Ensure the current chart ID is initialised in the environment
        if 'next_plotly_chart_id' not in env.temp_data:
            env.temp_data['next_plotly_chart_id'] = 0

        id = env.temp_data['next_plotly_chart_id']

        # Handle the URI of the *.json asset
        uri = directives.uri(self.arguments[0])

        # Create the main node container and store the URI of the file which will be collected later
        node = nodes.container()
        node['classes'] = ['sphinx-plotly']

        # Increment the ID counter ready for the next chart
        env.temp_data['next_plotly_chart_id'] += 1

        # Only if its a supported builder do we proceed (otherwise return an empty node)
        if env.app.builder.name in get_compatible_builders(env.app):

            chart_node = nodes.container()
            chart_node['classes'] = ['sphinx-plotly-chart', f"sphinx-plotly-chart-id-{id}", f"sphinx-plotly-chart-uri-{uri}"]

            placeholder_node = nodes.container()
            placeholder_node['classes'] = ['sphinx-plotly-placeholder', f"sphinx-plotly-placeholder-{id}"]
            placeholder_node += nodes.caption('', 'Loading...')

            node += chart_node
            node += placeholder_node

            # Add optional chart caption and legend (inspired by Figure directive)
            if self.content:
                caption_node = nodes.Element()  # Anonymous container for parsing
                self.state.nested_parse(self.content, self.content_offset, caption_node)
                first_node = caption_node[0]
                if isinstance(first_node, nodes.paragraph):
                    caption = nodes.caption(first_node.rawsource, '', *first_node.children)
                    caption.source = first_node.source
                    caption.line = first_node.line
                    node += caption
                elif not (isinstance(first_node, nodes.comment) and len(first_node) == 0):
                    error = self.state_machine.reporter.error(
                        'Chart caption must be a paragraph or empty comment.',
                        nodes.literal_block(self.block_text, self.block_text),
                        line=self.lineno)
                    return [node, error]
                if len(caption_node) > 1:
                    node += nodes.legend('', *caption_node[1:])

        return [node]
```

No matter where I look in the source code of the `Figure` and `Image` directives (on which I'm basing this) I can't figure out how to copy the acutal image from its input location, into the static folder in the build directory.

Without copying the `*.json` file specified in the argument to my directive, I always get a file not found!

I've tried hard to find supporting methods (I assumed that the `Sphinx` `app` instance would have an `add_static_file()` method just like it has an `add_css_file()` method).

I've also tried adding a list of files to copy to the `app` instance, then copying assets at the end of the build (but am being thwarted because you can't add attributes to the `Sphinx` class)

**QUESTION IN A NUTSHELL**

In a custom directive, how do you copy an asset (whose path is specified by an argument to the directive) to the build's `_static` directory?

Answer (score 1):

I realised it was straightforward to use sphinx's `copyfile` utility (which only copies if a file is changed, so is quick) right within the directive's `run()` method.

See how I get the `src_uri` and `build_uri` and copy the file directly within this updated `Directive`:

```
class PlotlyChartDirective(Directive):
    """ Top-level plotly chart directive """

    has_content = True

    def px_value(argument):
        # This is not callable as self.align.  We cannot make it a
        # staticmethod because we're saving an unbound method in
        # option_spec below.
        return directives.length_or_percentage_or_unitless(argument, 'px')

    required_arguments = 1
    optional_arguments = 0

    option_spec = {
        # TODO allow static images for PDF renders   'altimage': directives.unchanged,
        'height': px_value,
        'width': px_value,
    }

    def run(self):
        """ Parse a plotly chart directive """
        self.assert_has_content()
        env = self.state.document.settings.env

        # Ensure the current chart ID is initialised in the environment
        if 'next_plotly_chart_id' not in env.temp_data:
            env.temp_data['next_plotly_chart_id'] = 0

        # Get the ID of this chart
        id = env.temp_data['next_plotly_chart_id']

        # Handle the src and destination URI of the *.json asset
        uri = directives.uri(self.arguments[0])
        src_uri = os.path.join(env.app.builder.srcdir, uri)
        build_uri = os.path.join(env.app.builder.outdir, '_static', uri)

        # Create the main node container and store the URI of the file which will be collected later
        node = nodes.container()
        node['classes'] = ['sphinx-plotly']

        # Increment the ID counter ready for the next chart
        env.temp_data['next_plotly_chart_id'] += 1

        # Only if its a supported builder do we proceed (otherwise return an empty node)
        if env.app.builder.name in get_compatible_builders(env.app):

            # Make the directories and copy file (if file has changed)
            destdir = os.path.dirname(build_uri)
            if not os.path.exists(destdir):
                os.makedirs(destdir)

            copyfile(src_uri, build_uri)

            width = self.options.pop('width', DEFAULT_WIDTH)
            height = self.options.pop('height', DEFAULT_HEIGHT)

            chart_node = nodes.container()
            chart_node['classes'] = ['sphinx-plotly-chart', f"sphinx-plotly-chart-id-{id}", f"sphinx-plotly-chart-uri-{uri}"]

            placeholder_node = nodes.container()
            placeholder_node['classes'] = ['sphinx-plotly-placeholder', f"sphinx-plotly-placeholder-{id}"]
            placeholder_node += nodes.caption('', 'Loading...')

            node += chart_node
            node += placeholder_node

            # Add optional chart caption and legend (as per figure directive)
            if self.content:
                caption_node = nodes.Element()  # Anonymous container for parsing
                self.state.nested_parse(self.content, self.content_offset, caption_node)
                first_node = caption_node[0]
                if isinstance(first_node, nodes.paragraph):
                    caption = nodes.caption(first_node.rawsource, '', *first_node.children)
                    caption.source = first_node.source
                    caption.line = first_node.line
                    node += caption
                elif not (isinstance(first_node, nodes.comment) and len(first_node) == 0):
                    error = self.state_machine.reporter.error(
                        'Chart caption must be a paragraph or empty comment.',
                        nodes.literal_block(self.block_text, self.block_text),
                        line=self.lineno)
                    return [node, error]
                if len(caption_node) > 1:
                    node += nodes.legend('', *caption_node[1:])

        return [node]
```

Comment: I'm using the built-in `.. raw:: html` and I'm attempting to reference to an image foo.jpg at the same directory of the index.rst, however the output on ReadTheDocs does not contain my image foo.jpg. Do I have to use a customized directive for such a presumably common need?